# Xcode 7 Storyboard Unwind Segue with Swift Not Connecting to Exit

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, unwind-segue

Im trying to add a Cancel button and a segue back from an add scene.

I've created the function in my original view:

```
    @IBAction func cancelToMap(s:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

And ive used draged it to the exit and connected them both but i still get and error like this:

[image]

What am i doing wrong. Ive checked other threads and they are saying that u should add the code to the viewcontroller that ur trying to get back to but the thing is ive done that. The function is in that viewcontroller. Im new to Swift and Xcode and i dont understand when it gives me a "green" error with this text (lldb)

Comment: That's not an error. That's just a breakpoint. What does it say in the console output?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I had some code underneath it which was causing the error. Didnt even see it... Thanks for trying to help tho :-) Problem is solved! Worst thing is ive been trying different stuff for the last 3 hours haha